# Is AngularJS suitable for non SPA (Single Page Application)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm

I want to use AngularJS for non-spa app. Every page has own ng-app so:

Does the performance loss occurs?

and

Could you offer different MVVM framework for Non-SPA app?

Comment: This is contradictory to the idea of a SPA. In SPAs you do not have multiple pages (only multiple partials within the same application).

Comment: It will work just fine in non SPA's. Is there a performance hit? Yes: each page you go to requires a new Angular app to be instantiated ... you would not pay such a price in an SPA. Angular caches HTML templates (partials) and probably has many other optimizations that you would loose by instantiating a new app on each page. That said, your users would likely never notice the performance differences.